# how do i attach click handler/any event handler to my object or module

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i wanted to attach event handlers to my module i don't know how to achieve.

**below is my module:**

```
var globalModule = {

  name:'Banana on princess bed',

     init:function(){
         alert('Initialize');
     },

     getName:function(){
        return this.name; 
     }
}
```

the above `module` i will load for every page of my application or let say load in `index` page (available in every other page)

Suppose this is `page 1` (apart from index page) i want to listen for button click

```
<button id="button1">button 1</button>

$('#button1').on('click',function(){
    // execute some code
});
```

**Question:**  how do i handle `button1 click` from my `globalModule` and handle it

```js
var globalModule = {

  name:'Banana on princess bed',
    
     init:function(){
         alert('Initialize');
     },

     getName:function(){
        return this.name; 
     }
}

globalModule.init();

var name = globalModule.getName();

console.log(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

So, why do you think it isn't good enough to declare click event in your globalModule?
Please tell me the details.

```js
var globalModule = {

  name:'Banana on princess bed',
    
     init:function(){
         alert('Initialize');
         // Attach an event.
         $('.common1').on('click', function() {
             console.log('target-modal : ' + $(this).data('targetModal'));
         });
         $('.modal-submit').on('click', function() {
             // you need to manage to work properly.
             // Get root, then find parameter.
             // Of course, If you use form and prevent submit,
             // jquery serializeArray() is a good option.
             var thisModal = $(this).closest('.modal-root');
             console.log(thisModal.find('.param1').val());
             console.log(thisModal.find('.param2').val());
             console.log('go ajax : ' + $(this).data('url'));
         });
     },
     getName:function(){
        return this.name; 
     }
}

globalModule.init();

var name = globalModule.getName();

console.log(name);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

■other page1
<input class="common1" id="page1-common1" type="button" value="Common Button?" data-target-modal="modal1" data-url="[1]if ajax url is differenc, you need it">
<div id="modal1" class='modal-root'>
    <input type="text" value="page1-param1" class="param1">
    <input type="text" value="page1-param2" class="param2">
    <input class="modal-submit" type="button" value="submit1" data-url="[1]if ajax url is differenct, you need it">
</div><br>
■other page2
<input class="common1" id="page2-common1" type="button" value="Common Button?" data-target-modal="modal2">
<div id="modal2" class='modal-root'>
    <input type="text" value="page2-param1" class="param1">
    <input type="text" value="page2-param2" class="param2">
    <input class="modal-submit" type="button" value="submit2" data-url="[2]if ajax url is differenc, you need it">
</div>
```

Comment: On each page i have to `init` every `click` handler specific to page can't  I do? If I can please help me with that

Comment: in each **page** on `click` of some `button` i have to show `modal` and `post` the data

Comment: I assumed you include this module every page. Usually, If you want to create a common event, you just create a `common file(like common.js)`, then `attach an event` in that file. In that way, you don't need the module. If the process is different from each page, I think including globalModule doesn't make sense, but In your case, I think you can do that.

Comment: when you said "post", is it using ajax?, or normal submit?

Comment: `ajax` every where

Comment: Still, I need the information, but I update my answer. Is that what you want?